# Show number of live viewers on certain page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails and I am trying to get a live view count but not sure how to approach this. For example when someone goes to the page the count would go up by one then when the leave that page the count will go down by one. what is the best way to do this?

Comment: You could use javascript to poll an endpoint while a user is on the page. If you don't get a ping from the client for a whole polling period, then you can assume they left the page. You could also do this with a websocket.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think Google Analytics offer such thing, among with tons of other very interesting stats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used rails action cable then counted the number of users that were connected to the channel.

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem with ruby on rails. In my opinion, you should make the group of the views and make the controller of those.

If you can this step, you could control the pages with one controller. So in controller you should define like a variable. And then through this, you can do that functionality.

Thanks for your consideration!

Answer (score -1):

Rails uses REST ([wikipedia-Rest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)). That means a client just exchanges messages with your web-server, it doesn't create a permanent connection. Therefore, you can't count how long time a client browser in a page.